# Change vm page protection attributes from XNU kernel driver

Tags: macos, iokit, kernel-extension, xnu

As a part of an experiment i need to make a read-only page writable in kernel address space from a non-IOKit kext. In user mode i can do vm_protect, but there is surprisingly little info on how this can be done in kernel mode (or i am completely blind). Is there a call to do this?

Comment: Hi, I wonder if you manage to deal with this issue eventually, I'm currently trying to free memory after change it protection permissions with `vm_protect`, and get un-explained panic. perhaps you encountered such issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In the kernel, it's declared in `<mach/vm_map.h>`, and is part of the "unsupported" KPI. (Add com.apple.kpi.unsupported to OSBundleRequired of your kext's info.plist) I unfortunately haven't used this function from the kernel before, so I can't really comment beyond that. `vm_map_t` appears to be a Mach Port reference, but I'm not sure where you'd get it from.